# Why does the view not update when I update my JSX after initialization?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am a beginner in JSX and I need to use lifecycles to prevent some bug when loading an editor from primereact.

However, to make this example more simple, I want to update some string value after initialization and see it in my view.

This is my attempt:

```
let displayText = '<div>Hello World!</div>';

useEffect(() => {
    displayText = '<div>Bye World!</div>;
}, []);

return (<div>{displayText}</div>)
```

When I run this, I only see "Hello World!". But I expected to see "Bye World", since the variable got updated. What happened here? And how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try fixing the opening div tag here: `displayText = '>div>Bye World!</div>;`. I'm not sure this fixes your issue, but it needs fixing.

Comment: ahh thanks, I just wrote the code down instead of copying it

Comment: but this is not in my code^^

Comment: `return (<div>{displayText}</div>)` This will result in 2 sets of div tags. Try `return ({displayText})`

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800), what are you really trying to achieve? What's the real issue behind this?

Comment: Looks like you need `useState` to change your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an update to cause a render, you can't just assign a variable. A render is triggered after a prop change or a state change. Try converting your variable to a state:

```
const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState('<div>Hello World!</div>');

useEffect(() => {
    setDisplayText('<div>Bye World!</div>);
}, []);

return (<div>{displayText}</div>)
```

That way, after the first render, the effect will trigger, the state will change, and it will render again with the new value.

`useState` documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Also, you will render the string `<div>Hello World!</div>`, not a HTML `div` element.